# how to change the image of sign-in card?

Tags: bots, botframework

I am working on bot technology, in my current bot I used the sign-in card to authenticate my bot its working fine but I want to change the image of sign-in card.
[image]
Please tell me how to change the image of sign-in card.

-Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Right now it's not changeable @Pradeep.  We already have this request on the roadmap; but it's hard coded in some of the channels it's used in, so the SDK doesn't make it changeable.